# How to add two or more new lines in an expression in the main title in pheatmap

Tags: r, expression, pheatmap

I have a small question about expression when I use it in the pheatmap.

For example, I want to add information in the main title in a pheatmap plot with something in details. Here is my reproducible code:

```
# main <- expression(bold(paste(
#   atop(CD4_CD69^"+", 
#        "\nReported human signature core methylation genes"~n[tiles]~" = 1999;
#        "~n[genes]~"= 89")
#   )))

main <- expression(bold(paste(
  CD4_CD69^"+", 
  "\nReported human signature core methylation genes", 
  "\n", n[tiles], " = 1999;", n[genes], "= 89"
  )))   

test <- matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] <- test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] <- test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] <- test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) <- paste("Test", 1:10, sep="")  
rownames(test) <- c(paste("CGene", 6:10, sep=""), 
                    paste("AGene", 1:5, sep=""), 
                    paste("BGene", 11:15, sep=""), 
                    paste("DGene", 16:20, sep=""))


library(pheatmap)

p1 <- pheatmap(test, main="pheatmap")

p2 <- pheatmap((test), cluster_row=FALSE, 
               main=expression(bold(paste(
                 atop(CD4_CD69^"+", 
                      "Reported human signature core methylation genes"~n[tiles]~" = 1999;
                      "~n[genes]~"= 89")
                 ))))
```

It works well though with a little bit error information.

**But here, the main title information is long, so it seems that add two new lines to split the sentence into three lines is better.**

However, as we all know, "\n" doesn't work in expression. Though I can remove `expression` here.

But I don't know the other better methods to solve my problem.

I hope somebody or experts could give me some advice or solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use this workaround:

Create plot without title and then add multiline text with `grid` and `gridExtra` packages:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# heatmap without a main title
p2 <- pheatmap(test, cluster_row = FALSE)

# multiline title
title_grob <- textGrob(label = "CD4_CD69+\nReported human signature core methylation genes\nn[tiles] = 1999; n[genes] = 89",
                       gp = gpar(fontsize = 14))


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(title_grob, p2$gtable, heights = c(1, 10)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution. But I got the same method from CHATGPT. It's funny.

Comment: However, I have a new question. How can I save this picture produced by function grid.draw() as pdf with high dpi (1200) ?

Comment: Second question: it is not perfect because I want the "+" to be superscripted and the strings "tiles" and "genes" subscripted.  And then, add two new lines.  All of requests together above, I think is a little bit difficult.

Comment: Anybody could help me ??